# How do you get the id of an association in Ember without loading the association?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am trying to use the [Ember.Select](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html) view class, and I am looking for a way to retrieve the id of an association without loading the full model.

I am using Ember Data 1.0.0-beta.7. My property model looks like:

```
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Property = DS.Model.extend({
    neighborhood: DS.belongsTo('neighborhood'),
    name: attr()
});
```

An example of my payload looks like this:

```
{"property": neighborhood: 5, name: "Foo"}
```

I just need the id of the neighborhood in order to pass it to the select view value property so that it can be selected. I do not want to load the full neighborhood payload though because I only need the id.

Is there a way to do this without changing my model?

Comment: This has been a request from the community for quite a long time. As far as I know, there is no official way to do it. I think there might be a workaround using the `_data` and `_relationships` properties of the model, but I'm not sure as I don't use Ember-Data any more.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `property._data.neighborhood.id`.  The payload data is stored in the `_data` hash on the record, but it's not really recommended to use these!

I have a similar use case--I want to check if the record has a parent, but I don't actually want to retrieve the parent when I'm rendering a list.  Ember goes crazy and makes 100 requests, which is not exactly desirable!

Comment: And it's your choice if you want to use `property.get('...`--since it's outside the run loop/observers/etc. accessing it on the object is probably negligibly more performant.

Answer (score 0):

You can inspect the `belongsTo` relationship directly in a computed function.

```
import Ember from 'ember';
var attr = DS.attr;

App.Property = DS.Model.extend({
    neighborhood: DS.belongsTo('neighborhood'),
    name: attr(),

    neighborhoodId: Ember.computed(function(){
        return this.belongsTo('neighborhood').id();
    }).volatile()
});
```

Making the computed property `volatile` means that it is recomputed every time it is called - not only when new data comes in. This way, you don't always get an invalid value before the model is completely loaded.